# Effective custom azure table storage entity serialization?

Tags: .net, serialization, azure, azure-table-storage

Is there any way to effectively customize the serialization of an azure table storage entity? I already read many posts/topics about ReadingEntity/WritingEntity events, but I think that isn't sufficient for what I need. I want that my entities support:

1. Enum types properties;

- I have tested many options, more don't work for me, I receive an exception (status code 500), the ReadingEntity/WritingEntity event handlers aren't called and the entity is not persisted. Then, the event handlers approach doesn't work for this issue.

2. Read-only properties;

- In my test, I receive the exception ("The closed type System.String does not have a corresponding S settable property."), but the entity was persisted, then maybe I can just ignore the exception. The WritingEntity event handler is called, but I think that I maybe can't make nohting about the exception. The big problem is that the ReadingEntity event handler isn't called when I load the object, then I can't resolve this issue. Then, the event handlers approach doesn't work for this issue.

3. Transient/calculated properties;

- I have not tested, but I think that can be made with the event handlers approach, just remove property in the WritingEntity event handler.

4. Custom names to PartitionKey/RowKey elements;

- I don't have tested, but I think that can be made with the event handlers approach. I can use DataServiceEntity attribute in my entity class and make the rename, from my custom names to required names, in WritingEntity event handler.

5. Don't have a public default constructor.

- Ok, this has worked fine in my test.

Well, the issues 1 and 2 remain a big problem for me, anybody has any idea for I accomplish all 5 goals?

Thank's..
Best regards..

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest the [FatEntity](https://github.com/Lokad/lokad-cloud/wiki/FatEntities) approach of Lokad.Cloud. It's simpler and more efficient in our experience.

Comment: Hi Joannes, I agree that FatEntity is a good general approach, but I would like try anything more especific, in some few cases I want be able to query by properties of entities.

Comment: Query entities by properties is a big no-no, properties are not indexed. Performance falls apart as soon you have more than a few thousands entities. Been there, and been severely burned already.

Comment: Hi Joannes, of course, I know this performance issue. But, I would like have this option for specific cases and, I don't wait for this, but in some future time this can be added the property index feature. :) Do you know some way to accomplish all 5 goals?

Comment: No sorry. Plus, I would not count too much on the extra indexes as well.